# PHP Regex Make leading zero a mandatory

Tags: php

I am trying to validate an input and the rules (conditions) are:

1. The value should be exactly 11 characters long and digit only
2. The value should start with `Zero '0'`

I have managed to find a solution for rule number one and the code looks like following

```
$str='01272095631';
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{11}+$/', $str)) {$error= "Yes";} else {$error= "No";}

echo $error;
```

Could you please help me with the rule number 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking to complicated. Keep things simple:

`/^0[0-9]{10}$/`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match('/^0[0-9]{10}+$/', $str)) {
    $error= "Yes";
} else {
    $error= "No";
}

echo $error;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly reduced pattern :)

```
'/^0\d{10}$/'
```

Comment: You're missing the delimiters.